# LAMP Server not working on Precise

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, lamp

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise a few days ago. I tried installing LAMP Server as I've been done in last four Ubuntu versions, simply by using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

First command seems to install all needed packages for LAMP to work. It installs and configures Apache Server, PHP Modules and MySQL server, all in one. Second one installs phpMyAdmin, which I'll need for MySQL database management.

But when I open: `http://localhost` on my browser, nothing happens. The default page that says "It Works!" isn't shown. I tried restarting Apache a lot of times with this command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But no luck. Anyone got anything similar?

Comment: Is there the index.html file inside /var/www?

Comment: Can you show your config file?

Comment: Paste the output of `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for messages.

Comment: @harisibrahimkv Yes there is. Here's its contents:

    <html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
    <p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
    <p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
    </body></html>

Comment: @Lekensteyn Here's last errors from this file:

[Wed May 02 11:19:44 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 02 11:19:45 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Please put this information in your question, so it doesn't get buried in the comments!

Answer (score 2):

Solved my problem. My pc is under a network w/ proxy authentication, and my configs were blocking access through http://localhost. It's working fine if I access through http://[my_IP_address], so all I did was configure my pc network settings properly with the help of our network admin.

Thanks anyway :)